# Pull a list of names from one column based on text in a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I've got a list or names in column A. The manager for each person is listed in column M. Each manager could have 8-15 reps.

On a separate sheet, I want to be able to have a formula that basically looks at column M to find a specific manager's name and then lists all of their reps.

Perhaps the first formula in a column finds a rep's name that reports to the manager. The following formula looks for another name that isn't the one above. The following looks for a name that isn't one of the names already found? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) is the perfect solution.